# Inject code into JNI function (Android shared library)

Tags: android, arm, shared-object

An android app loads a native library (`.so`) using `System.loadLibrary`. It then calls a specific function, which takes 3 input variables, and returns a string containing a MD5 hash.

You can see the relevant part of the function below:

[image]

I want to be able to see the original, "unhashed" message (which is of course derived from the 3 input variables), instead of it's md5 hash. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: You can use Frida to hook the `MD5_Update` function.

Comment: @0xec this worked perfectly. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @0xes I'm trying to reverse engineer hash generation in an Android app. I suppose Frida is the right tool for this too? I was able to hook to the app. But there are some things I'm a bit confused about. How would I find out which function is doing it? After I have the function name, how would I get the contents of the function?

Comment: Any news about this? I am trying to do samething.

Comment: @BerkayYıldız there already is an accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Frida](https://www.frida.re).

Frida is a dynamic binary instrumentation tool that allows you to intercept, trace, modify, ... of a running application using a JavaScript debugging logic.

For your purpose, you need to hook the `MD5_Update` function using the [`Interceptor`](https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#interceptor) API.

The JavaScript code may look like the following. [Warning: Untested]

```
// Use the mangled form of name MD5_Update below
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName("mylib.so", "MD5_Update"), {
    onEnter: function (args) 
    {
        var ptr_data = args[1];
        var length = args[2];    

        var data = Memory.readByteArray(ptr_data, length);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

#### Further reference:

- https://11x256.github.io/
- https://www.notsosecure.com/instrumenting-native-android-functions-using-frida/
- https://enovella.github.io/android/reverse/2017/05/20/android-owasp-crackmes-level-3.html